# javax.annotation.Injected outside of service is always null

Tags: java, dependency-injection, wildfly, java-ee-8

I have a WildFly server (**without Spring**) in which one of the classes requires an injection to happen. Something like this:

```
class Foo {
    @Inject
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    ...
}
```

However each time the class is created `myInterface` is null. Class `Foo` is not created inside any service class, but the call happens from a service class. To simplify:

A service call (wsdl to be specific) → static method from other class is called → that method creates instance of `Foo`

The class that implements `MyService` is annotated with `@Named` and `@ApplicationScoped`. When the `@Inject` with `MyInterface` is in a service class (exact same code as in `Foo`) it's correctly injected. But not for non-service classes.

Comment: Is class Foo a CDI or EJB?

Comment: It's not EJB, so it ought to be CDI

Comment: What is `Foo` annotated with?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It's not annotated with anything. Should it be annotated with something?

Comment: Yes. For CDI to work all beans need to be managed. IoW you can't do something like `new Foo()` and have CDI work. It needs to manage the lifecycle of all components involved.

Comment: What should I annotate `Foo` with?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're doing something in the likes of:
`Foo foo = new Foo();`

Well, you can't. If you want to inject inside Foo, you also needs to let CDI manages Foo. If you create it yourself with `new`, then it is not a CDI bean and thus it cannot use CDI features.

So first you need to annotate your Foo class. The annotation depends on what you want it to do. Let's say you need a instance for each new http request and you need it to dies when the http request ends. In this case it will be

```
@RequestScoped
class Foo {
    @Inject
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    ...
}
```

See here for more details on what annotations to use: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic008.htm

and then, on the class that is calling Foo, you need to do something like

```
class FooCaller {
    @Inject
    private Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that the FooCaller caller also needs to be a CDI bean.